# log file search based on date and time range on multiple log files using awk

Tags: awk

I have log files spread out on various log files ( basically they are set to rotate the logs ). I need to extract the logs based on date with time..
sample log file has the below.

```
2012.12.06 01:56:01 AUTH_SERVER.VMP_SYS [main - ] <INFO   > Loaded properties
2012.12.06 01:56:01 AUTH_SERVER.VMP_SYS [main - ] <INFO   > Initialized logging
2012.12.06 01:56:01 AUTH_SERVER.VMP_SYS [main - ] <CONFIG > Log levels =
```

I have tried with the below awk one liner...

```
awk -F - '"2012.12.06 01:56:01" < $1 && $1 <= "2012.12.08 04:30:00"' server.log   server.log.1
```

this prints out what is needed...

but would like to use the for loop to run through the list of log filenames that is extracted in a txt file using this

```
find server.log* -exec ls -lth {} \; | awk '{print $9}' > logfilenames.txt
```

i need to use logfilenames content ( this has the full path of the log files in that directory ) as inputs in the for loop to search for the correct log file names from start date time till end date time and output it to different file.

Need help with the for loop to complete this script.

Comment: good question, but we can't tell what you expect to be in logfilenames.txt. A full path, the complete listing of `ls -lth` OR ?? Please edit your question to include required output for filel logfilenames.txt. Good luck.

Comment: logfilenames.txt...would have outputs from the   find server.log* -exec ls -lth {} \; | awk '{print $9}' as /directory/subdirectory/logs/server.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just do

`awk -F - '"2012.12.06 01:56:01" < $1 && $1 <= "2012.12.08 04:30:00"' server.log*`

also,

```
cat `cat logfilenames.txt`
```

will cat all the files contained in logfilenames.txt. You can run awk on the output.

you can also use xargs and redirect the output of grep to awk. So to use the two commands that you have given you can do this:

```
find server.log* -exec ls -lth {} \; | awk '{print $9}' | xargs awk -F - '"2012.12.06 01:56:01" < $1 && $1 <= "2012.12.08 04:30:00"'
```

Comment: well, that certainly works...Thanks. but how do i awk on the output? also,what if i wanted to output to the user saying that the start date and time and end date time is located at these server log files...that would just be good information for the user point of view.

Comment: how do i redirect this to an output file..?  awk -F - '"2012.12.06 01:56:01" < $1 && $1 <= "2012.12.08 04:30:00"' server.log*

Comment: Logfile="$HOSTNAME.log"


awk -F - '"$starttime" < $1 && $1 <= "$endtime"' server.log* > "$Logfile"
This doesn't seem to work...

Comment: this is because "$starttime" and "$endtime" are not available to awk. You need to use [-v option](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Assignment-Options) to pass bash variables to awk script, but it will require rewrite of your one liner script.

Comment: The meta-`cat` is kind of cute but that's still a [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html).  I would perhaps use `xargs cat <logfilenames.txt` instead.